# refactoring towards.net core api conventions

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

In our application we are using mediatr and there is a common pattern as follows:

```
class SomeController
{
    public Action Foo(SomeRequest request)
    {
       var result = Mediatr.Send(request);
       if(result == null)
       {
          return NotFound();
       }
       return Ok(result);
    }

}
```

This code repeats for every API end point, regardless of the HTTP method.

I read about API conventions but I guess that is about Swagger, API analyser and such.

How can I avoid having this repetetive code above?

Answer (score 0):

```
class BaseController
{
     protected static IActionResult GenericAction(object request)
     {
           var result = Mediatr.Send(request);
           if(result == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }
           return Ok(result);
     }
}
```

Then

```
class SomeController : BaseController
{

    public Action Foo(SomeRequest request)
    {
         return GenericAction(request);
    } 
}
```

if your methods always has same structure you can even generalize it more

```
class BaseController<TRequest>
{ 
     public virtual Action Foo(SomeRequest request)
     {
         return GenericAction(request);
     } 


     protected static IActionResult GenericAction(TRequest request)
     {
           var result = Mediatr.Send(request);
           if(result == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }
           return Ok(result);
     }
}
```

Then

```
class SomeController<SomeRequest> : BaseController
{
}
```